# How to add common/inc folder to a CUDA project at Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, nvidia, gpu

I want to develop gpu computing algorithms using CUDA. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition. After I install all the computing tools and SDK with samples, I see under project types "NVIDIA->CUDA->CUDA 4.0 Runtime" choice to start a CUDA project.

The problem is that I can't include source files located at ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0/Common/inc to work with samples, use header files under GL directory etc. I'm trying to include them using "Additional Include Directories". I'm adding the full path, but it doesn't work. Visual Studio doesn't see those files.

How can I use these files? What should I type in to get these files?

I compiled cutil project under common directory, it solved some error problems while trying to compile samples but it made no use for the issue I stated above.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to install CUDA into VS2010.

1. Create a normal project of your choice. (e.g. win32)
2. Right click the project and choose Build Customizations. If you have installed the tools and SDK correctly you should see a CUDA 4.0 target. (If your project becomes corrupt you may also have to replace the existing ExtensionSetting import in your .vcxproj file)

   > ```
   > <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
   >           <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props"/>
   >     </ImportGroup>
   > ```
3. Your include path should already be setup, if it is not then add $(CUDA_INC_PATH) to your VC++ include directory.
4. Add cudart.lib to your Linker additional libraries ensuring that $(CudaToolkitLibDir) is added to the paths.
5. Create a file and give it the .cu file extension. Right click the file, go to properties and select the Item Type as "Cuda C/C++".

Once sthis i complete you should be able to compile Cuda in VS2010. I may have forgetten some steps, you may need to fiddle abit, I will edit this post if I recall tomorrow.